How to add TextBox to fabric.js after loading from JSON
I am unable to load json into fabric.js (via canvas.loadFromJSON) and then create a TextBox which I add to the canvas. The image shows, but the TextBox does not show.
I believe the issue might be because I'm loading a type image. In the examples on fabricjs.com, it shows loading rect or circle. Or, whilst this is a difference, there is something else that is wrong entirely.
I've created some code that demonstrates this.
https://jsfiddle.net/cbp612wo/1/
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const jsonWithShape = JSON.stringify({"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":150,"width":150,"height":150,"fill":"#29477F","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"rgba(94, 128, 191, 0.5)","blur":5,"offsetX":10,"offsetY":10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0}]});

const jsonWithImage = JSON.stringify({"objects":
    [{
        "type": "image",
        "version": "5.2.1",            
        "src": "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-screen.svg"
    }]
});

//Uncomment one or the other of the lines 2 lines below - the text only shows on the shape (rect) 
//canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonWithShape);   //this works as expected
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonWithImage);     //this does not show the text

const txt = "Hello world";

const t1 = new fabric.Textbox(txt, {
    textAlign: 'center'
});

canvas.add(t1);
     
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)

</script>

In the example above, I've commented out one of the lines so you can essentially toggle between a working example (by commenting/uncommenting where specified).
I can work around this - instead of calling canvas.loadFromJSON() I can deserialise the json with JSON.parse(), and then iterate over each object, and use fabric.image.fromObject(myObj, function(img){canvas.add(img);}); but, that isn't my question (and I leave work around for anyone who might find it useful)
What am I doing wrong? Why can't I see text and the SO logo?

Use a callback to be sure that your text is added after the canvas restoration of canvas.loadFromJSON() because the
loadFromJSON(json, callback, reviveropt) → {fabric.Canvas}



Name
Type
Attributes
Description




callback
function

Callback, invoked when json is parsed and corresponding objects (e.g: fabric.Image) are initialized



canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonWithImage, () => {

 // canvas is restored, add your code.

  const t1 = new fabric.Textbox(' "Hello world"', { textAlign: 'center' });
  canvas.add(t1);
  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});    

//this now show the text


You should look to upgrade your fabric.JS version to V6
because now those method work around with Promise instead of callback
example for V6
canvas.loadFromJSON(json).then((canvas) => canvas.requestRenderAll());

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function(o, object) {
  // `o` = json object
  // `object` = fabric.Object instance
  // ... do some stuff ...
}).then((canvas) => {
  ... canvas is restored, add your code.
});


Do you know where version 6 is, as a single .js file? I'm used to going to places like jquery and downloading a single file. Maybe I'm too out of date, but when I browse fabric GitHub, I don't see a javascript file (something like fabric.min.js). If I download the latest (from tags) I get a bunch of .ts files and folders.

JsDelivr here here
